# Custome ItemReader for reading each iteration of a for loop

Tags: spring-batch

Recently started working with Spring Batch chunk based processing. I need to create batch for creating random 3 million strings, 1 million each of different type and count. Like a million strings starting with A, next 1.5 million ending with GH. Cannot do it with for loop as it will block a thread. I have to write them in db also. No idea how to make my  ItemReader read each iteration.

I have understood the custom ItemReader through [this](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-creating-a-custom-itemreader/) 
but not getting what should be the "item" here.
If i create a chunk of 1000, then how the counters will be handled, counting the chunk entry and the string generated counter.

Comment: When you say you need to create those strings you mean you really want to synthesize them as (probably) test data, as opposed to reading them from some resource. Correct?

Comment: Right. I will receive a list of  [suffix, a prefix and a count N]. Based on some logic, I have to create N strings using that suffix and prefix from 1 set. So I thought to create a class (let) C having fields "suffix", "prefix"and "count"
Then my reader should read set of objects of type C; processor should process that C into List<String> and writer should write  that list.

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemReader` interface is quite similar to an `Iterator` and like that has to maintain the iteration state internally. The Spring Batch framework even provides an `IteratorItemReader`.
Since Java 8 there are Streams, which I find quite versatile also for generating data and which can be converted into an `Iterator`.
Here is a possible solution along the lines of what you described:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Java8StreamReaderTest.TestConfig.class, properties = {"spring.batch.job.enabled=false"})
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Java8StreamReaderTest {

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory(final JobRepository jobRepository) {
            return new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository);
        }

        @Bean
        StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory(final JobRepository jobRepository, final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
            return new StepBuilderFactory(jobRepository, transactionManager);
        }

        @Bean
        Job streamJob() {
            return jobBuilderFactory(null).get("streamJob")
                    .start(stepBuilderFactory(null, null).get("streamStep")
                        .<String, String>chunk(1000)
                        .reader(streamReader())
                        .writer(listWriter())
                        .build()
                )
                .build();
        }

        @Bean
        ListItemWriter<String> listWriter() {
            return new ListItemWriter<>();
        }

        @Bean
        ItemReader<String> streamReader() {
            return new IteratorItemReader<String>(stream().iterator());
        }

        @Bean
        Stream<String> stream() {
            return Stream.of(
                IntStream.range(0, 100000).boxed().map(i -> {
                    return new String("A"+ RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, false));
                }),
                IntStream.range(0, 100000).boxed().map(i -> {
                    return new String("B"+ RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, false));
                }),
                IntStream.range(0, 100000).boxed().map(i -> {
                    return new String(RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, false) + "GH");
                })
            )
            .flatMap(s -> s);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    Job streamJob;

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    ListItemWriter<String> listWriter;

    @Test
    public void shouldExecuteTestJob() throws Exception {
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(streamJob, new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters());
        assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, execution.getExitStatus());
        assertThat(listWriter.getWrittenItems(), hasSize(300000));
    }
}
```

Comment: What I could get from the sample is:
1) while creating the job by streamJob(), in reader you are creating all the 3m records altogather by streamReader()->stream().iterator()
2) after they are created, the listWriter() is going to write the stream of strings received into a List in chunks of 1000.
Mi getting correct. If so, isn't this stream() method creating stream of 3m strings going to take time.

Comment: A `Stream` works in a lazy fashion, producing each item only on demand, just like `ItemReader` itself. The stream() method just sets the stream up but does not itself generate the strings. That`s why it doesn’t take much time.